# Creating a UDF in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create a UDF named maxDate in BigQuery that does the following:

maxDate('table_name') returns the result from running the query below:

select max(table_id) from fact.___TABLES____ where table_id < 'table_name';

I'm quite new to JS and not too sure how to start. This looks like a simple thing to write. Could anyone point me in the right way? I've read the documentation, and unsure of how to write this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar UDF are not existent yet in BigQuery
See more about [BigQuery User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) to understand what are they today.
To simplify  - think of today's UDF as virtual table that you can query and this table in turn powered by real table where each row is processed row-by-row and javascript code is applied for each row and generates (instead of this input row) zero, one or many (depends of inplemented in js logic) rows)

Comment: Can you elaborate what scalar UDF means? It looks like you can only create a UDF that wraps the resultset of a subquery, correct?

Comment: scalar UDF is udf that can be applied to field(s) and used in SELECT statement vs. table wise UDF is used in FROM. so yes - correct - you apply currently available udf to whole set/table/[sub]query. note: above scalar udf definition is quite simplified  - just to give you an idea